# What is $T^1(\mathbb H^2/PSL_2(\mathbb Z))$?

Tags: riemannian-geometry, hyperbolic-geometry, ergodic-theory, diophantine-approximation

Let $\mathbb H^2$ be the upper-half plane.
The group $PSL_2(Z)$ acts on $\mathbb H^2$ by isometries, and hence we get an action on $T^1(\mathbb H^2)$.
This action is free, smooth, and proper, and thus $X=T^1(\mathbb H^2)/PSL_2(Z)$ is a smooth manifold (with unique smooth structure such that the projection $T^1(\mathbb H^2)\to T^1(\mathbb H^2)/PSL_2(Z)$ is a submersion).

In [these](http://chrome-extension://oemmndcbldboiebfnladdacbdfmadadm/https://www.math.uzh.ch/gorodnik/tifr/lecture1.pdf) notes, on page 3, the first line reads that: Note that $X$ is a unit tangent bundle of non-compact hyperbolic surface (with two "singular points").

I am unable to make sense of this statement. Can somebody please explain how we can see $X$ as the unit tangent bundle of a Riemannian manifold?

Also, what is meant by 'singular points' here?

Thank you.

**Edit.** **Definition of $T^1$:** Let $(M, g)$ be a Riemannian manifold. Then $T^1M$, the **unit tangent bundle** of $M$, is the collection of all the members of $TM$ which are of unit length. Now since $\mathbb H^2$ is a Riemannian manifold (the metric being $(dx^2+dy^2)/y^2$), we can talk about $T^1(\mathbb H^2)$.

Comment: See page $5$ [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1705.04760.pdf), why the unit tangent bundle of the modular surface $M=\Bbb H^2/PSL_2(\Bbb Z)$  is just the quotient space $X=PSL_2(\Bbb R)/PSL_2(\Bbb Z)$.

Comment: The document mentions that $\mathbb H^2/PSL_2(\mathbb Z)$ is not a manifold but an "orbifold". In that case it is not clear what is the meaning of $T^1(\mathbb H^2/PSL_2(\mathbb Z))$. I looked up the definition of an orbifold on wikipedia but didn't help. Can you say what is going on here?

Comment: Yes, the fibered bundle has singularities at the elliptic fixed points, but this can be fixed, see S. Katok, Fuchsian groups, $§ 3.6$.

Comment: $\mathbb{H}\to \mathbb{H}/PSL_2(\mathbb{Z})$ is a submersion? What is the differential at $i$ or $1/2+i\sqrt{3}/2$?

Comment: @Unpud For $\mathbb H\to \mathbb H/PSL_2(\mathbb Z)$ to be a submersion the target has to be a manifold. But it is not. Or were you trying to say something else?

Comment: I think the target is a manifold, in particular a Riemann surface. But the quotient map is not a submersion.

Comment: I think $\mathbb H^2/PSL_2(Z)$ is homeomorphic to the two dimensional open ball (which is same as $\mathbb R^2$ of course), and therefore it does admit a smooth structure. In fact, for reasons unknown to me, there is a unique smooth structure on it.  So you have a point.

Comment: I think there should be a unique complex structure making the projection from $\mathbb{H}$ holomorphic. But with this structure the quotient map has points with differential $0$. So the hyperbolic metric wouldn’t descend at those points. I don’t know what people mean when they say ‘unit tangent bundle to the modular surface’.

Comment: @Caffeinemachine already gives the correct definition of the `unit tangent bundle to the modular surface' in his question, namely: $PSL_2(\mathbb Z)$ acts naturally on $T^1 \mathbb H^2$ by the derivative maps of the natural action of $PSL_2(\mathbb Z)$ on $\mathbb H^2$; this action is free and properly discontinuous and the geodesic flow is equivariant with respect to this action; $T^1(\mathbb H^2 / PSL_2(\mathbb Z))$ is the quotient, equipped with the quotient flow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key word here is [Seifert fiber spaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seifert_fiber_space) (don't be fooled by the Wikipedia link, Seifert fiber spaces do not have to be closed manifolds).

Oriented 3-manifolds $M$ that fiber over a connected 2-manifold $S$ with circle fiber $C$ have a pretty simple classification theory. That theory has a few intricacies in the case that $M$ (and $S$) is closed, centered on the concept of the Euler number of the fibration. However, if $M$ (and $S$) are not closed then the classification is very simple: each is fiber isomorphic to the product $C \times S$.

More generally, an oriented Seifert fibered 3-manifold $M$ has the structure of a fibration in the category of orbifolds, where the base 2-orbifold $O$ is oriented and hence is a surface with a collection of singularities each determined by its order (a natural number $\ge 2$), and where the generic fiber is a circle. The Siefert fiber structure has a local invariant over each singularity of $O$, which describes how the generic circles over points near $O$ wind around the singular circle wind over $O$; this invariant is a rational number modulo $1$, whose denominator is equal to the order of the singularity. Again, the full classification theory is complicated by Euler number if $M$ is closed, but when $M$ is not closed (equivalently $S$ is not closed), the Siefert fiber structure is completely determined by the local invariants.

I'm not going to write a treatise on the local invariants of singular fibers of Seifert fiber spaces, but I'll tell you how to proceed once you learn that theory.

In the case of $T^1(\mathbb H^2 / PSL_2(\mathbb Z))$, the base orbifold $\mathbb H^2 / PSL_2(\mathbb Z)$ is an open disc with an order 2 and an order 3 singularities. You can calculate the values of the local invariant of the singular fibers of $T^1(\mathbb H^2 / PSL_2(\mathbb Z))$ over those two singularities, by examining, for each $p \in \mathbb H^2$ with an order 2 or 3 stabilizer subgroup in $PSL_2(\mathbb Z)$, how that subgroup acts on $T^1_p(\mathbb H^2)$. That way you will have completely worked out the classification of $T^1(\mathbb H^2 / PSL_2(\mathbb Z))$ in Siefert fiber space language.

But, if you want to know some familiar example which is homeomorphic to $T^1(\mathbb H^2 / PSL_2(\mathbb Z))$, I think that's also possible: I believe it may be homeomorphic to the complement of the trefoil knot in $S^3$. That complement has the same base orbifold as $T^1(\mathbb H^2 / PSL_2(\mathbb Z))$ --- the open disc with an order 2 and order 3 singularity --- but I do not know offhand the local invariants of two singular fibers. One might also be able to directly compare the fundamental groups of those two 3-manifolds.

Comment: Isn't $\mathbb{H}/PSL_2(\mathbb{Z})$ a smooth manifold? Near the fixed points, isn't the action isomorphic to the quotient of the disc by some finite rotation group? So near a point with stabilizer of order $2$, wouldn't a coordinate chart be realised by a map of the form $z\mapsto z^2$? Similarly, for points with stabilizer of order $3$?

Comment: I should say, the coordinate chart is given by the homeomorphism $D/(\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}) \to D$ induced by $z\mapsto z^2$.

Comment: It is indeed true, as you say, that the smooth structure which $\mathbb H / PSL_2(\mathbb Z) - \{\text{the two cone points}\}$ inherits from $\mathbb H$ extends to a smooth structure on the whole of $\mathbb H / PSL_2(\mathbb Z)$. But that's a different thing from saying $\mathbb H / PSL_2(\mathbb Z)$ inherits a smooth structure from $\mathbb H$.

Comment: Isn’t there a unique complex structure making the quotient holomorphic?

Comment: On the other hand, the orbifold structure on $\mathbb H / PSL_2(\mathbb Z)$ *is* naturally inherited from $\mathbb H$. The conformal structure that $\mathbb H / PSL_2(\mathbb Z) - \{\text{the two cone points}\}$ inherits from $\mathbb H$ also extends naturally over $\mathbb H / PSL_2(\mathbb Z)$, because the singularities where those two cone points were removed are, indeed, removable singularities.

Comment: Nonetheless, this is all kind of a side issue to the question asked. The concept which points towards an answer is the orbifold structure on $\mathbb H / PSL_2(\mathbb Z)$.

Answer (score 1):

If $\Gamma$ is a torsion free lattice in $G:=PSL_2(\mathbb{R})$, thus acting freely and discontinuously on $\mathbb{H}$, one can unambiguously make sense of $T^1(\Gamma\backslash\mathbb{H})$ since $\Gamma\backslash\mathbb{H}$ is a nice Riemannian manifold with the projection preserving the Riemannian metric. Moreover, one can identify $\Gamma\backslash G$ with $T^1(\Gamma\backslash\mathbb{H})$ and one can see that the $\mathbb{R}$-action of diagonal matrices with entries $\lbrace e^{t/2},e^{-t/2}\rbrace$ is intertwined with the geodesic action on $T^1(\Gamma\backslash\mathbb{H})$ under this identification.

But in general when $\Gamma$ is has some fixed points, the notation $T^1(\Gamma\backslash\mathbb{H})$ becomes ambiguous\innacurate as you have noticed. However, there is still the space $\Gamma\backslash G$ with a nice action by diagonal matrices. Most authors continue to work the the diagonal matrix action on this space and simply call it the 'unit tangent bundle over $\Gamma\backslash\mathbb{H}$' with the 'geodesic action' as an abuse of notation (cf. the book by Bekka-Mayer, page $59$).

As a beginner in ergodic theory, I have noticed that working with torsion lattices in $G$ is quite a headache. In Bekka-Mayer's book, they assume torsion-free-ness for a number of their results simply for convenience (cf. section III$.3$, page $93$).