# Tangent bundle on modular surface

Tags: hyperbolic-geometry, tangent-bundle, modular-group

Let $\mathbb{H} = \{x+iy: y > 0\}$ be usual the complex upper half plane.

The modular group is defined to be $$PSL(2,\mathbb{R}) = SL(2,\mathbb{R})/\{I_2, -I_2\}.$$ So it is a class of matrices where $M$ and $-M$ are identified.

Similarly, a modular surface is $$PSL(2,\mathbb{Z}) \backslash \mathbb{H}$$ which I believe the same thing as $$\mathbb{H} / SL(2,\mathbb{Z}).$$ Not totally sure how moding occur since $\mathbb{H} \subseteq \mathbb{C}$ and $SL(2,\mathbb{Z}) \subseteq SL(2,\mathbb{R}),$ they are not the same object "a complex points" and a "matrix".

Thebn there is a fact, which most text/documant about hyperbolic geometry mentioned without proof

"we can identify the unit tangent bundle on modular surface with $$SL(2,\mathbb{R}) / SL(2,\mathbb{Z})"$$

(for example one good text available online is https://webusers.imj-prg.fr/~antonin.guilloux/notes.pdf?fbclid=IwAR0SN5LhHC_yOWn0_Hx6fQ_NDK6aPYHFi07rdH3ycp8quDH6wxV-7330dzQ and it mentioned this fact briefly on page 7)

So identify here mean a bijection between two sets ? I do not quite understand how to see this. Can anyone give some help please ?

Comment: Take a look [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3087566/what-is-t1-mathbb-h2-psl-2-mathbb-z?rq=1).

Comment: It isn't quite the same --- your action is presumably on the left, hence modding $SL(2,\mathbb{Z})\setminus\mathbb{H}$ as opposed to modding on the right.

Comment: Note that $\operatorname{PSL}(2,\mathbb{R})$ acts on the upper half plane $\mathbb{H}$ by Möbius transformations, $$\begin{pmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{pmatrix}.z:=\frac{az+b}{cz+d}.$$ This is how the quotient is build. For the sphere bundle: First prove that $\operatorname{PSL}(2,\mathbb{R})\cong S\mathbb{H}$, the unit tangent bundle of $\mathbb{H}$. For this recall the Iwasawa decomposition and show that $K:=\operatorname{PSO}(2,\mathbb{R})$ fixes the point $i\in\mathbb{H}$ and rotates the direction in this point, whereas you can shift arbitrary points in $\mathbb{H}$ to $i$ using $A$ and $N$.